# a command box for updating data on a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good day guys I created a userform on excel with a combobox and a command button, the command button is for updating the data on the spread sheet based on the item selected on the combobox and a textbox with data, the problem is every time I click the command button it does not update the data, instead it goes to the next column and fill it in. and i want the data to be updated on the item selected

this is what I tried

```
  Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim lrCD As Long
    lrCD = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrCD + 1, "A").Value = ComboBox1.Text
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrCD + 1, "B").Value = TextBox5.Text
```

Comment: Do you mean it goes to the next row?  Your click event finds the last row in column A and then adds the text to the next row down.  Change `Cells(lrCD + 1, "A")` to a constant if you want to update the same cell each time `Cells(1, "A")`.

Comment: i tried doing that i even tried using Cells(lrCD, "A"),the probem is that the updated data goes to the next row down

Comment: There must be some other code that's mucking it up - I tried the exact code you've posted, removed the `+1` and it always updated the same row based on the last row found in column A.

Comment: i am using row select to populate the combobox, and that row is row A on sheet 2, now row B needs to be updated, but instead it does not update the selected item

Comment: Think I'm getting confused with your English.... the combo box contains the values in column A on sheet2.  When you select one of those values in the combo box it will find that value in column A and update the adjacent value in column B with whatever text is in the textbox.  I think that's what you're asking?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your form as below:

[image]

Column A in `Sheet2` contains unique values that will appear in your combobox.

This code sits within the form.
The `UserForm_Initialize()` event fires when you open the form and will populate the combobox with values.
The `CommandButton6_Click` event searches column A and places the text in textbox5 next to the selected value.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lrCD As Long
    'Populate ComboBox with values from column A on Sheet2.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lrCD = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "'Sheet2'!" & .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lrCD, 1)).Address
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim rCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        'Look for the selected value in column A.
        Set rCell = .Columns(1).Find( _
            What:=Me.ComboBox1.Value, _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole)

        'If a value is found place the textbox value in the column next to it.
        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            rCell.Offset(, 1) = Me.TextBox5.Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]